# How to replace class name inside div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div id="payment_group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label for="form_control_1">Paid Amount</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" id="Paid_amount" name="Paid_amount" style="" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
            <label>Payment Mode</label>
            <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="Payment_mode" id="Payment_Mode" onchange="show_bank()">
                <option value="">Select Payment Mode</option>
                <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                <option value="Card">Card</option>
                <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to replace col-md-6 with col-md-4 inside div id payment_group by using jQuery? Sorry for my weak English.

Comment: Does this work? `$("#payment_group .col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4").removeClass(".col-md-6");`

Comment: Yes but col-md-6 is located at almost in the whole web page I just want to replace col-md-6 to col-md-4 that located inside id payment_group.

Comment: Try this:
$("#payment_group>div.col-md-6").removeClass("col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4");

Comment: Exactly, see how #payment_group comes before .col-md-6  `"#payment_group .col-md-6"` That's how css-works. Left to right takes you further down the nested elements.

Comment: @admcfajn the comment was before you edited yours... It did not contain the ID part originally...

Comment: But why? if you replace 6 with 4, only 2/3rd of the space will be used and 1/3 will be blank.

Comment: Yes, That's right @Salketer I re-read the question a moment later. I should get some sleep, take care! Nice touch with `toggleClass`, that option came to my mind too.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you could simply do this:

```
$('#payment_group .col-md-6').toggleClass('col-md-6 col-md-4');
//Or
$('#payment_group .col-md-6').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6"‌​);
```

The toggle option is not the best, it will add a class if it does not exist and remove it if it does... It's a bit more concise tough...

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="payment_group">
<div class="col-md-6" id="changeclass">
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
        <label for="form_control_1">Paid Amount</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" id="Paid_amount" name="Paid_amount" style="" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

add one id named="changeclass" for col-md-6 div

then in jquery

```
$("#changeclass").toggleClass('col-md-4');
```

Comment: Why would it be necessary to add an id?

Comment: Have tried the above solution.If its not working let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#payment_group .col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6")`

**Working demo**

```js
$("#payment_group .col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6")
console.log("elements with class col-md-4: " + $("#payment_group .col-md-4").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="payment_group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label for="form_control_1">Paid Amount</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" id="Paid_amount" name="Paid_amount" style="" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
            <label>Payment Mode</label>
            <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="Payment_mode" id="Payment_Mode" onchange="show_bank()">
                <option value="">Select Payment Mode</option>
                <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                <option value="Card">Card</option>
                <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use addClass() and removeClass()

```js
$("#payment_group .col-md-6").addClass('col-md-4').removeClass('col-md-6')
```

```css
.col-md-4 {
  color: red
}

.col-md-6 {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="payment_group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
      <label for="form_control_1">Paid Amount</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" id="Paid_amount" name="Paid_amount" style="" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
      <label>Payment Mode</label>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="Payment_mode" id="Payment_Mode" onchange="show_bank()">
                <option value="">Select Payment Mode</option>
                <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                <option value="Card">Card</option>
                <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
            </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class regardless of what it was.

```
$("#payment_group .col-md-6").attr("class", "class-name-you-want-to-assign");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#payment_group").find(".col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4");
$("#payment_group").find(".col-md-6").removeClass(".col-md-6");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
$( "#payment_group div:first-child" )
    $( this ).removeClass( ".col-md-6" );
    $( this ).addClass( ".col-md-4" );
});
```

Thanks

Comment: First off you are using a `}` but i see no `{`, second even if you add `{` it would not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove the class

```
$(selector).removeClass(classname,function(index,currentclass))
```

And to add

```
$(selector).addClass(classname,function(index,currentclass))
```

[You can check w3schools site here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeclass.asp)

[and for add class, check this.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**I think this will going to help u as well !**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#payment_group .col-md-6').toggleClass('col-md-6 col-md-4');
           });     
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="payment_group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                <label for="form_control_1">Paid Amount</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" id="Paid_amount" name="Paid_amount" style="" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                <label>Payment Mode</label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="Payment_mode" id="Payment_Mode" onchange="show_bank()">
                    <option value="">Select Payment Mode</option>
                    <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                    <option value="Card">Card</option>
                    <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="gete">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) for this:

`$('#payment_group').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6");`